# How do I read the data sent to my express route?

Tags: javascript, express

I don't know why, but when I try to view my data using `req.body.newFullName` I get an empty object. The post is going to the correct route but I don't know how to access the form's field data that was sent by the XMLHttpRequest.

Below is most of the code I used.

route setup `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index'); 
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
module.exports = app;
```

route details `users.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
/* POST contacts */
router.post("/", function(req,res,next){
  data = req.body.newFullName;

  res.send(data);
})
module.exports = router;
```

form details `index.html`

```
...
<form id="contacts">
<label for="FullName">Full Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="newFullName" placeholder="Enter Full Name..."><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit data">
</form>
...
```

js that submits form data

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    function createContact(){
        var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var frmData = new FormData(form);
        XHR.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/users/");
        XHR.send(frmData);
    };
    var form = document.getElementById("contacts");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        createContact();
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your server code sends back the data as-is, and your client code discards the reply. Did you try something like `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: the console.log comes back as `[object Object]`

Comment: Right, now try `console.log(req.body.newFullName);`

Comment: It returns `undefined`. I used a package `json-stringify-safe` to look at the object and body is an empty object `{}`. I am so confused because this is basically an app generated by express generator. I didn't add much. I see the data in the outgoing request, using my browser inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the client-side code; you're sending `multipart/formdata` but expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` on the server.

Here's the current way to send that:

```
function createContact() {
    const payload = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form));
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: payload
    })
    .then(rawReply => rawReply.text())
    .then(reply => console.log("reply", reply))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
};
```

If you check the request in the browser, you'll find it now properly shows the params instead of raw text.

Comment: I have to run by i will try this when I get back home!

Comment: I am testing with your function and running into some issues but your assessment is correct. Using the "formData" object only sends the data as a `multipart/formdata`. I used an XMLHttpRequest and you use a fetch so I am going to keep working on this so I can do it with a XMLHttpRequest. Thank you! You helped me figure out what I was missing! I found a package called [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) that might help me through this.

Comment: UPDATE: multer did fix the issue for me. I added multer to the api route and my problems are gone. The req.body field has the data I was looking for now. I really appreciate the help. Happy new year.